# Is it possible to shrink the root partition?

Tags: filesystem, partition, root

Extracted from the instructions from the [original docs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) for installing Ubuntu on RaspBerry Pi 2:

> There are no Raspbian-specific utilities included, specifically no automatic **root resizer**. However, it's not hard to do manually. Once
>   booted
>
> $ sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0
>
> Delete the second partition (d, 2), then re-create it using the
>   defaults (n, p, 2, enter, enter), then write and exit (w). Reboot the
>   system, then:
>
> $ sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2

By using this method, the 2GB **root partition** extracted from the .img Ubuntu file can be **expanded** to the full size of my, say, 32GB SD card.

Is it possible to **revert this step to shrink** the, say, 32GB root filesystem size, to something smaller like, say, 4GB (assuming, of course, that filesystem has no more than that 4GB data full)?

Comment: Questions about resizing linux partitions really belong on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/); `fdisk` and `resize2fs` aren't unique to the Pi or Ubuntu.   See also `man resize2fs`.   You can do this in reverse but the filesystem must be unmounted.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to connect the card to Linux PC and shrink the partition via GParted.

Comment: Well, indeed, this is the (nearly) obvious method. My question was rather talking about reverting the same method or similar, due to the advantages of not needing a second computer. Anyway, your answer is correct. I will, however, give priority to more directs methods.